# Wordpress Home/Front Page Display at top of Admin Pages List

Tags: wordpress

I know this example doesn't show a lot of pages. But, on sites with dozens of pages, I have to go to the next page, scroll, sort by title, etc. to find the home page. Is there a way to have the home/front page always appear at the top of the list.

[image]

Comment: With this question you will probably be better off in the Wordpress StackExchange Community: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

By default, the WordPress pages list is ordered by menu order and then alphabetically. Knowing that, you can set the menu order for each page with the home page at 0 and everything else higher. If you set everything else at (for example) 1, those pages will come after the Home Page and then be ordered alphabetically. Or, you can set a fully custom menu order and your pages will be ordered accordingly.

In addition, plugins like this one (https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-page-ordering/) will allow you to drag and drop reorder the pages so you can pull everything below the Home Page. (This plugin sets the menu order of the pages based on how you drag and drop them.)